# justification of $\operatorname {E} \left[2X\operatorname {E} [X]\right] = 2\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [X]$

Tags: probability

I am learning [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition).

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\operatorname {Var} (X)&=\operatorname {E} \left[(X-\operatorname {E} [X])^{2}\right]\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}-2X\operatorname {E} [X]+\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\right]\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-2\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [X]+\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\end{aligned}}}
$$

where, the part

$$\operatorname {E} \left[2X\operatorname {E} [X]\right] = 2\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [X]
$$

is a little bit difficult to justify, can anyone give a hint? which rule can apply this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Linearity of Expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) applys this.

let $a = \operatorname{E}[X]$, which is a constant

your formula is now $\operatorname{E} \left[ 2X a \right] = 2\operatorname{E}[X] a  = 2\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [X]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\mathrm{E}[X]$ is a constant, so can be pulled outside the expectation.