# how to justify the formula about Sample variance

Tags: probability

inspired by this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221749/justification-of-operatorname-e-left2x-operatorname-e-x-right-2-ope), i am trying to justify the formula about [Sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).

[image]

I guess the term in yellow box comes from the term in red box

the question is, how to justify the terms in blue box.

Comment: does this link meet your need? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1hgiAla3KI